# Sum values where date is less than 14 days

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

In Crystal Reports, I have three fields.

Field 1: Allocation sum field

Field 2:  DatePaid

Field 3: Formula:  Greater Than 2 Weeks field.

I need to find the sum total of Allocation if the DatePaid field is less than 14 days.

Thanks!

Jim
In Crystal Reports

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula following the logic of:

```
IF Your_Condition THEN Your_Value ELSE 0
```

Then, simply SUM it.